# How do I execute a function on a repository in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I had a similar problem to this one, but that solution doesn't seem to apply here. I'm trying to invoke an overloaded repository funtion to sort my view data in accordance with the select option choosen on the view dropdown.

I used the "onchange" event to execute my javascript, but I'm stuck trying to execute the repository function because th the overloads don't match and I'm not sure how to bind them properly. Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

**My Html View**

```
<select id="sortSelect" onchange="CallChangeFunction()">
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="make">Make</option>
    <option value="model">Model</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
</select>

<script>
    function CallChangeFunction(val) {
        alert("Do something here to make it sort!");
    }
</script>
```

**My Listing Repository**

```
IEnumerable<ListingStat> GetListingStats(int inCompanyID, int inMonth, int inYear);


public IEnumerable<ListingStat> GetListingStats(int inCompanyID, int inMonth, int inYear)
{
    //var x = document.getElementById("sortSelect").value;

    // there's probably a way to make ef do this query in an efficient manner.. but, there aren't nice keys between listingstats and makemodel stats, and I'm not going to create them for the sake of ef
    var theSQL = "select d.DatePK, ls.*, " +
                 "mm.Make as MM_Make, mm.Model as MM_Model, mm.ListingsThatWereActive as MM_ListingCount, mm.MedianPriceExcludeZero as MM_MedianPrice, mm.PopularityRank as MM_PopularityRank, " +
                 "mm.PopularityMaxRank as MM_PopularityMaxRank, mm.AverageFavorites as MM_Favorites, mm.AverageSearchImpressions as MM_SearchImpressions, mm.AverageBuyerInquiries as MM_BuyerInquiries, mm.AveragePhoneInquiries as MM_PhoneInquiries, mm.AverageListingViews as MM_ListingViews, " +
                 "ymm.SupplyDemandIntegerPercentile as YMM_SupplyDemandPercentile, ymm.TotalListingViews as YMM_TotalListingViews " +
                 "from " +
                 "PerformanceDataMart.Dates d " +
                 "left outer join PerformanceDataMart.ListingStats ls on ls.DateFK = d.DatePK and ls.CompanyId = :CompanyID " +
                 "left outer join PerformanceDataMart.MakeModelStats mm on mm.DateFK = d.DatePK and mm.Make = ls.Make and mm.Model = ls.Model and mm.Year is null " +
                 "left outer join PerformanceDataMart.MakeModelStats ymm on ymm.DateFK = d.DatePK and ymm.Make = ls.Make and ymm.Model = ls.Model and ymm.Year = ls.Year " +
                 "where d.Month = :Month and d.Year = :Year";

    var theDB = new CCDB();

    List<ListingStat> theList = new List<ListingStat>();

    using (IDataReader aDR = theDB.OpenDataReader(theSQL, inCompanyID, inMonth, inYear))
    {
        while(aDR.Read())
        {
            ListingStat theListingStat = new ListingStat();
            theList.Add(theListingStat);

            theListingStat.ListingId = As.Integer(aDR["ListingId"]);
            theListingStat.Year = As.Integer(aDR["Year"]);
            theListingStat.Make = As.String(aDR["MM_Make"]);
            if (theListingStat.Make == "")          // shouldn't happen, but just in case
                theListingStat.Make = As.String(aDR["Make"]);

            theListingStat.Model = As.String(aDR["MM_Model"]);
            if (theListingStat.Model == "")             // shouldn't happen, but just in case
                theListingStat.Model = As.String(aDR["Model"]);
        }
    }

    return theList;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please mention specifically what you are not able to do. Are you unable to call the desired action method from the javascript or ... from controller to your desired repository method.

Comment: I'm trying to call the action method from the javascript on my html view. I don't know how to handle the overloaded method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Jquery on page and try this one:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#sortSelect").change(function () {
            alert("test");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Won't that just give me what I have now, an alert that tells me I need to call the method?

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the types and order of the params in the ajax call same as the data types and order of your controllers overloaded function.

Your function will look something like this:

```
function CallGetListingStats(inCompanyID, inMonth, inYear) {
    var model = {
        "inCompanyID": inCompanyID,
        "inMonth": inMonth,
        "inYear": inYear
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/YourControllerName/YourMethodName",
        type: "Post",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // do anything here after controller call
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```